# I am trying to us this formula =AND(COUNTIF(A2;"*"&$C$2:$C$5&"*")) in VBA code but get error 13

Tags: excel, vba, countif

The goal is to check if all names in the list in column C are in a cell in column a.
The result should be true or false.
It works with the formula in the sheet, but not with the sample VBA code I created.
The result in column b with the formula would be:

```
FALSE   
FALSE   
TRUE   
FALSE
```

, as the third row column a has all the names (and more) that are in the list in column c.

I converted it to look like this:

```
Sub CI()
Cells(7, 2) =  
Application.WorksheetFunction.And(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells(2, 1),  "*" & Range("C2:C5") & "*"))
End Sub
```

| Column A | Column B | Column c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| names | in list | list |
| corne giancarlo | `=AND(COUNTIF(A2;"*"&$C$2:$C$5&"*"))` | corne |
| corne onur | `=AND(COUNTIF(A3;"*"&$C$2:$C$5&"*"))` | giancarlo |
| corne giancarlo marcin onur | `=AND(COUNTIF(A4;"*"&$C$2:$C$5&"*"))` | marcin |
| giancarlo marcin | `=AND(COUNTIF(A5;"*"&$C$2:$C$5&"*"))` |  |

Any help is much appreciated. :-)

Comment: Thanks for editing Dominique. Looks better now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a custom function and call from the cell. As you know, put absolute range($) to the list range as example below.
**At cell B2 : =isAllNamesInRange(A2,$C$2:$C$4)**

isAllNamesInRange function returns True if all names in the 'list' are found in the 'names' range, otherwise False

```
Public Function isAllNamesInRange(names As Range, list As Range) As Boolean
    Dim name As Range
    Dim flag As Boolean
    
    ' Initialize the result variable as True
    isAllNamesInRange = True
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the 'list' range
    For Each name In list
        ' Check if the current 'name' cell's value is found within the 'names' range
        If InStr(names, name) > 0 Then
            ' If found, set the 'flag' to True
            flag = True
        Else
            ' If not found, set the 'flag' to False
            flag = False
        End If
        
        ' Update the result by multiplying it with the 'flag'
        ' If any 'flag' is False, 'isAllNamesInRange' will become False
        isAllNamesInRange = isAllNamesInRange * flag
    Next name
    
End Function
```

Comment: Works like a charm @vbakim, thank you. (Y)